# How to use theme parameter CSS classes in my app?

Tags: sapui5

I want to change theme using sap UI5 and I found the [Theme Parameter Toolbox](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/test-resources/sap/m/demokit/theming/webapp/index.html).

I'm just wondering how the theme parameters can be used as class. e.g. `<Link class="sapUiLink" />`.

Any ideas how to use this theme parameter toolbox?

There was no any description to use it.

Comment: here is the description: [1](https://blogs.sap.com/2019/10/23/sap-fiori-theme-customization/), [2](https://blogs.sap.com/2014/05/16/how-to-set-a-theme-parameter-to-sap-fiori-launchpad/). have you tried anything?

Comment: @Suncatcher Thanks for the links but, i am not using fiori (Currently I am using ui5 + node.js with sap cloud.) I'm just wondering that Theme Parameter Toolbox can be use as class. ex) <Link class='sapUiLink' /> something like this.

Comment: yes, it can be. Read the links thoroughly, it's all there

Answer (score 0):

You can use method sap.ui.core.Theming.Parameter('Your theme paramter')

Or

Write the css class.
sapThemeText-asColor{
color:@sapUiText
}

Second approach is rule based css.